# Package Control installed on Sublime Text 3 but the list not shown

Tags: sublimetext3, package-control

I am using Sublime Text 3 on Windows 7 with Package Control installed. I was able to use package control to install packages with it. But now I found that package control doesn't show up in the list when I press `ctrl+shift+p`. I am able see package control item in the preference menu. I have checked `Settings-user` and `Settings-default`, package control is not listed as ignored package. I also checked the `Installed Packages` folder and found that the `Package Control.sublime-package` is in it.

Why is that Package Control is not showing up in the list? How can I fix it?

Comment: This is a longshot, but do you have Package Control set as one of your ignored packages in your user settings file? That's the only way I was able to replicate this issue.

Comment: @saadq Nope, it wasn't set as ignored package in user settings file.